# Alert Box to show when error occur

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-modal

I am looking to implement the bootstrap alert boxes, for when I have a concurrency error on a page. Currently this is how the Controller is setup:

Comment: I think you should remove a lot of useless stuff. Which is the call you want to show the alert for?

Comment: @TonySamperi I am looking to get an error message to show for a few errors, how would I do it for this one: 'private const string ConcurrencyError = "The following song failed to verify as another user has since changed its details.";'

Comment: Is there a way I can create the alert to show when one of the errors is called as I have a few errors. I am just looking for a way to get an error message to show.

Comment: are you using something like bootstrap.js? Anyway I would use this https://sweetalert.js.org/ it's really cool

Comment: I'm posting an answer...it should help.

Comment: @TonySamperi I am using bootstrap unfortunately. So I would like to use bootstrap alerts

Comment: You can use my answer as well. I created a code which generates the list of errors. You can put it into the bootstrap modal.

Just replace the swal with the $.modal()

Comment: I am just wondering if its possible to show the error based on the ones that are in the controller, how I would show it on the view.

Comment: Look at the answer.

Comment: I switched to bootstrap. Take a look now

Comment: I dont want to use `window.genericErrorMsg = "There was a server error, please contact the support desk on (+44) 0207 099 5991.";`

I would like to use what is in place currently.

Comment: Do what you want with the generic error. The rest doesn't change

Comment: Just use the error callback you had before..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171526/discussion-between-tony-samperi-and-rob).

Comment: The answer doesnt work, is there a simple way using sweetalert2 that I can show a list of errors from the controller in the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this with sweetalert2:

https://jsfiddle.net/x07g89h9/

or with **bootstrap**

https://jsfiddle.net/mmq27s86/2/

**HTML**

declare bootstrap modal

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Errors</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <ul id="errors">

         </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
  function showModal(errors){
        var $msg = $("#errors");
        $msg.empty();
        for(var i=0; i<result.errors.length; i++){
             $msg.append("<li>" + errors[i] + "</li>");
        }
        $('#myModal').modal();
   }

   $.ajax({
            url: 'any...',
            data: JSON.stringify(model),
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (result) {



                // in case of error
                if(result.ChangeStatus !== "Success"){

                     showModal(result.errors);
                }
            },
            error: function () { 
                $('#errorContainer').show(); 
                $('#errorMessage').html('There was a server error, please contact the support desk on (+44) 0207 099 5991.'); 
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Just tried it and its not showing the errors correctly.

Comment: I gave you 2 fiddles. Stack overflow is not meant for people to work for you. It's meant for hints and tips. I gave you 2. And they work perfectly. You have to adapt your code to work with mine.
You should now select my answer as correct.

Comment: Anyway, I don't know C#. You should put your errors list in the json response.
Try adding this line in the success: `console.info("RESULT", result)` and see what happens in your browser's console

Comment: @Rob if you show me a screen of the console with the line above I'm still glad to help

Comment: I have decided to use sweet alert, I am just trying within ajax on the error to show a message.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://forums.asp.net/t/2115958.aspx?Using%20bootstrap%20alert%20in%20asp%20net) or [this](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2904/alerts-in-bootstrap).

Articles are too long to report whole code here.